# Mule - Removing a given key from a map in Groovy component

Tags: groovy, mule, mule-component

I need to remove a key from a map in groovy. I have seen through many posts and tried doing this :

```
   def mymap = message.getInboundProperty("http.query.params");

   mymap.remove('thatKey');
```

The above code doesn't work for me and throws error:

```
    Message               : Failed to invoke ScriptComponent{GlobalProductDataStoreIntegrationMainFlow.component.1929599908}. Component     that caused exception is: ScriptComponent{GlobalProductDataStoreIntegrationMainFlow.component.1929599908}. Message payload is of     type: NullPayload
Type                  : org.mule.component.ComponentException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
Payload               : {NullPayload}
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/component/ComponentException.html
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. null (java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException)
  java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap:1345 (null)
2. java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException (javax.script.ScriptException)
  org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl:348 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/script/ScriptException.html)
 3. Failed to invoke    ScriptComponent{GlobalProductDataStoreIntegrationMainFlow.component.1929599908}.      Component that caused     exception is:    ScriptComponent{GlobalProductDataStoreIntegrationMainFlow.component.1929599908}.        Message payload is of type: NullPayload (org.mule.component.ComponentException)
  org.mule.component.AbstractComponent:142 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/component/ComponentException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.remove(Collections.java:1345)
at org.mule.module.http.internal.ParameterMap.remove(ParameterMap.java:112)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting **UnsupportedOperationException** because the map is immutable; it cannot be modified. The workaround is to create a new map which excludes the entry you don't want:

```
def mymap = message.getInboundProperty("http.query.params").findAll { 
    it.key != 'thatkey' 
}
```